# How to get the content of iframe in Java (Selenium)?

Tags: java, html, selenium, iframe

I need to get whole content of an iframe using selenium API in java.

This is the expected result:

```
<div id="WIN_0_304255502" arid="304255502" artype="View" ardbn="z2VF_02" 
        arcontainerid="304255802" arpercentwidth="100" 
        arpercentheight="100" class="arfid304255502 ardbnz2VF_02" 
        ardcf="1" style="top: auto; left: auto; width: 1318px; 
        height: 744px; z-index: 1135; min-width: 20px; 
        max-width: 32767px; min-height: 20px; 
        max-height: 32767px; position: relative; overflow: hidden;
        background-color: transparent;" 
        arvfframe="<iframe style=&quot;top:0px&amp;#59; left:0px&amp;#59; width:1170px&amp;#59; 
        height:744px&amp;#59;
        background-color: transparent&amp;#59;&quot; name=&quot;VF304255502&quot; frameborder=0 
        scrolling=&quot;no&quot; 
        allowtransparency=&quot;true&quot; arviewbordercolor=&quot;null&quot; title=&quot;z2VF_02&quot; src=&quot;javascript:&amp;quot;&amp;lt;HTML&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/HTML&amp;gt;&amp;quot;&quot; 
        onload=&quot;DVFol&amp;#40;&amp;#41;&quot;>
        </iframe>
        " arwindowid="0" arstop="1">

        //more elements
```

For now I try:

```
WebDriver driver= new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get(url3);
saveFile(driver.getPageSource());
```

After run the program, the result that I have it´s not what I expected. Maybe because of iframe that exists.

Result:

```
<div id="WIN_0_304255502" arid="304255502" artype="View" ardbn="z2VF_02" arcontainerid="304255802" 
        arpercentwidth="100" arpercentheight="100" class="arfid304255502 ardbnz2VF_02" 
        ardcf="1" style="top:0px; left:0px; width:1170px; height:744px;z-index:1135;background-color:transparent;min-width:20px;max-width:32767px;min-height:20px;max-height:32767px;" 
        arvfframe="&lt;iframe style=&quot;top:0px&amp;#59; left:0px&amp;#59; width:1170px&amp;#59; 
        height:744px&amp;#59;background-color: transparent&amp;#59;&quot; name=&quot;VF304255502&quot; 
        frameborder=0 scrolling=&quot;no&quot; allowtransparency=&quot;true&quot; arviewbordercolor=&quot;null&quot; 
        title=&quot;z2VF_02&quot; src=&quot;javascript:&amp;quot;&amp;lt;HTML&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/HTML&amp;gt;&amp;quot;&quot; 
        onload=&quot;DVFol&amp;#40;&amp;#41;&quot;>
        &lt;/iframe>
    ">
     </div>
```

I also try to access iframe (`driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("VF304255503")`), but occurs an exception (`org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element with name: VF304255503`).

Comment: Are you sure that `VF304255503` is not dynamically generated?

Comment: Yes, after you said that, I see that `VF304255503` is dynamically generated.
So, I save this on a String and I try again `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name(nameIframe)`, but the error still occurs.

Comment: If anyone knows how to do it, please tell me. It´s a little bit urgent.

Comment: Do you mean that the `VF304255503` value changing every time you refresh the page? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but now this is not a problem because I make a function that searches the `VF304255503` value (name of the iframe attribute). My problem it´s how to access the iframe. I want to see the elements bellow that.
Thanks.

Comment: Every websites that I see talking about iframes inside div's, shows how to access the information of an iframe tag. In this case, the iframe is an attribute. This is the problem.